# javascript Const behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand the const variable type in the sample code below

```js
try{
   const fax = 2234;
   fax = 3.45 + 20;
   console.log("fax", fax);
}catch(err){
   console.log("err", err);
}
```

As per ES6 `const` variable type not re-assignable. I am expecting an error for the fax variable. but the expected actual is 23.45

How can `const` variable value change ?

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: It will throw error TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? You can only re-assign `fax` in IE11 because it's not actually ES6 compliant. The implementation of `const` and `let` is *exactly* the same as `var`, IE11 just aliased the new declaration keywords to the old one.

Comment: "but the expected actual is 23.45" what do you mean? Do you **expect** `fax` to be 23.45 or do you **actually** get 23.45?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in JavaScript `const` is like `let` but the only thing is once initialised by a value then it can not be changed through out the execution of the script.
that's what `const` is for (it stands for constant)

consider the following code

```
{
    const a = 10
    console.log(a)
}
a = 1000
console.log(a)
```

you would get 10 and 1000 logged on the console because `const` is similar to `let` except that its value can not be changed once assigned within a code block
consider another code below

```
{
    const a = 10
    console.log(a)
    a = 20 // since you are assigning another value to a const variable inside the same code block will be an error
}
a = 1000
console.log(a)
```

you would get an error as `assignment to constant variable` after logging 10

click [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to know more about `let`

Answer (score 0):

When you defined variable using `const` keyword you cannot reassignment a value to it after defined it

**[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) refers that**

> The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment

So if you want to reassignment a value to the variable you should use `let` keyword instead of `const`, as the following

```js
let fax = 2234;
fax = 3.45 + 20;
console.log("fax", fax);
```

Comment: W3Schools - subtly wrong, as sadly usual. You also cannot change object values assigned to a `const`. You can change the object *contents* but not its value. At any rate, the question is *why* is `fax` re-assignable, not *how* to make it re-assignable.

Comment: @VLAZ "**Constant Object** can change, **Constant Array** can change but **Primitive Values** cannot change." w3schools already referred to that. I corrected my answer

Comment: @AmjedOmar: w3schools is still subtly wrong simply because there isn't a concept of a "constant object" and it conflates *values* with *bindings*. The reality is: There are two types of bindings: changeable and unchangeable (const) ones. There are two types of values: mutable and immutable values. That leaves us with four value-binding combinations.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, I understood, I corrected my answer